# SQL Server : find producent with atleast 3 unique speeds of Processor

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I need to find producents with 3 UNIQUE SPEEDS of processors.

I have 2 tables `Products` (producent, model, type) and `PC` (model, fast, ram, disc, price)

I just did and I have no idea how to count them from my select

```
select distinct  
    P.producent, Pc.fast 
from 
    pc Pc 
join 
    Product P on P.model = Pc.model 
group by 
    P.producent, fast
```

Desired output

```
producent
--------------------
A
D
E
```

Table and values

```
CREATE TABLE Product
(
    producent VARCHAR(20),
    model INTEGER,
    type VARCHAR(20)
);

CREATE TABLE PC
(
    model INTEGER,
    speed DECIMAL(10, 2),
    ram INTEGER,
    disc INTEGER,
    price INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE Laptop
(
    model INTEGER,
    fast DECIMAL(10, 2),
    ram INTEGER,
    disc INTEGER,
    screen DECIMAL(10, 1),
    price INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE Printer
(
    model INTEGER,
    color BIT,
    type VARCHAR(20),
    price INTEGER
);
GO

INSERT INTO Produkt 
VALUES ('A', 1001, 'pc'), ('A', 1002, 'pc'), ('A', 1003, 'pc'),
       ('A', 2004, 'laptop'), ('A', 2005, 'laptop'), ('A', 2006, 'laptop'),
       ('B', 1004, 'pc'), ('B', 1005, 'pc'), ('B', 1006, 'pc'),
       ('B', 2007, 'laptop'), ('C', 1007, 'pc'), 
       ('D', 1008, 'pc'), ('D', 1009, 'pc'), ('D', 1010, 'pc'),
       ('D', 3004, 'printer'), ('D', 3005, 'printer'), 
       ('E', 1011, 'pc'), ('E', 1012, 'pc'), ('E', 1013, 'pc'),
       ('E', 2001, 'laptop'), ('E', 2002, 'laptop'), ('E', 2003, 'laptop'),
       ('E', 3001, 'printer'), ('E', 3002, 'printer'), ('E', 3003, 'printer'),
       ('F', 2008, 'laptop'), ('F', 2009, 'laptop'), ('G', 2010, 'laptop'),
       ('H', 3006, 'prinet'), ('H', 3007, 'printer');

INSERT INTO PC VALUES
(1001, 2.66, 1024, 250, 2114),
(1002, 2.10, 512 , 250, 995 ),
(1003, 1.42, 512 , 80 , 478 ),
(1004, 2.80, 1024, 250, 649 ),
(1005, 3.20, 512 , 250, 630 ),
(1006, 3.20, 1024, 320, 1049),
(1007, 2.20, 1024, 200, 510 ),
(1008, 2.20, 2048, 250, 770 ),
(1009, 2.00, 1024, 250, 650 ),
(1010, 2.80, 2048, 300, 770 ),
(1011, 1.86, 2048, 160, 959 ),
(1012, 2.80, 1024, 160, 649 ),
(1013, 3.06, 512 , 80 , 529 );
```

I also tried something like this

```
select pro.producent 
from produkt pro 
join pc p on pro.model = p.model 
group by pro.producent 
having count(p.speed) = 3
```

but it also didn't work because I need UNIQUE speeds.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: It's probably going to be using SUM or COUNT but we need to see sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this code,

`SELECT P.producent, PC.fast, COUNT(*) quantity FROM pc PC INNER JOIN Product P on P.model = PC.model GROUP BY P.producent, PC.fast`

Remove distinct, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/EN-US/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/ms132161(v=sql.110)) more info, and add Count [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) more info.

Maybe, you must read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/grouping-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

**UPDATE 1:**

OK, you have to run this subquery:

`SELECT A.producent FROM (SELECT P.producent, PC.fast, COUNT(*) quantity FROM pc PC INNER JOIN Product P on P.model = PC.model GROUP BY P.producent, PC.fast)A GROUP BY producent HAVING COUNT(1) >= 3`

**UPDATE 2:**

With Cross Apply function the query must be:

`SELECT P.producent FROM Product P
CROSS APPLY (SELECT PC.fast FROM pc PC WHERE P.model = PC.model GROUP BY PC.fast HAVING COUNT(1) >= 3)A`

[This link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/) contains helpful information about CROSS APPLY and OUTER APPLY.

Comment: You are great. Thank you, subquery solved this problem

Comment: Ok, exist another approach with CROSS APPLY function. let me know if you want to know more about this

Answer (score 0):

`inner join` could be helpful in this case:

```
select * from Products inner join PC on Products.model = PC.model

where fast in (SELECT DISTINCT fast FROM PC)
```

and speed >= value

ORDER BY fast

Answer (score 0):

Solved problem

```
SELECT A.producent FROM (SELECT P.producent, PC.fast, COUNT(*) quantity FROM pc PC INNER JOIN Product P on P.model = PC.model GROUP BY P.producent, PC.fast)A GROUP BY producent HAVING COUNT(1) >= 3
```